# How can I enable full screen option on Safari browser in iPhone?

Tags: javascript

Below code, full screen option not working safari browser on iphone, But it working fine Mac,iPad and windows laptop and android mobile. How to fixes this issue?

```js
var devTag = document.getElementById('iframe_container');
if (devTag.requestFullscreen) {
    devTag.requestFullscreen();
} else if (devTag.mozRequestFullScreen) { // Firefox
    devTag.mozRequestFullScreen();
} else if (devTag.webkitRequestFullscreen) { // Chrome, Safari, and Opera
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPod/i)) {
        // Fallback for older versions of Safari on iPhone
        devTag.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else {
        devTag.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
    }
} else if (devTag.msRequestFullscreen) { // IE/Edge
    fullscreenImage.msRequestFullscreen();
}else{
    alert("Fullscreen mode is not supported in this browser");
}
```

Try to Full screen all browser in all device, But this code not working on iPhone device.

Answer (score -1):

Is it a [`<div>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div) element? If I understand correctly, it's not supported on iPhone or has some issues. [Learn more.](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/133248)

Comment: Code updated, div is var devTag = document.getElementById('iframe_container');

Comment: @TharinduAnjana According to the above thread, there are some problems from Apple side.